# How do I get rid of Spring warning: Running `gem pristine --all`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the [Spring application preloader](https://github.com/jonleighton/spring) and just upgraded to v 0.9.0. Now I'm getting the following warning:

> Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs will improve the startup performance of Spring.

I tried running that command but it fails to install some of my gems, which may have to do with my recent upgrade to OS X Mavericks. How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was because previous versions of rubygems would load all the gemspecs whenever queried.

This is slow to begin with and gets slower the more gems are installed.

But with Rubygems 2.1 it has a "stubbed" gemspec that is very fast to load.  See https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/435 for more info.

The spring people take advantage of this to not load every single gemspec when just loading bin/spring which uses just a small number to call out to the spring server.

The test it was doing (assuming you have RubyGems 2.1 or later) was essentially:

```
ruby -e 'p Gem::Specification.stubs.reject(&:stubbed?).reject(&:default_gem?).map(&:name)'
```

If that list was not empty, it knew that you had older gems; gems installed with RubyGems < 2.1.

You can use that information to generate a list of gems to run `gem pristine` on:

```
# /tmp/dirty.rb
require 'shellwords'


Gem::Specification.stubs.reject(&:stubbed?).reject(&:default_gem?).each do |gemspec|
  puts "gem pristine #{Shellwords.escape gemspec.name} --version #{Shellwords.escape gemspec.version.to_s}"
end
```

Then just run:

```
ruby /tmp/dirty.rb | bash
```

But it is easier to run `gem pristine --all` and as @Beerlington mentioned, `gem uninstall` any gems giving it a problem.

Comment: Though this didn't exactly solve my problem on Ubuntu 14.04, it led me to https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/320#issuecomment-252131401 which suggest Ubuntu/Debian uses a package that messes with the behavior of `default_gem?`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't totally understand the [source of the issue](https://github.com/jonleighton/spring/blob/master/bin/spring#L8-L26), but I was able to get rid of the warning by removing the gems that were failing to install and then rerunning `gem pristine --all`. It's probably not a huge issue, but I figured I'd post my solution in case someone else comes across the same problem.